# NullPointerException when extending persistent CFC

Tags: inheritance, orm, coldfusion, nullpointerexception, cfc

The error occurs when attempting to extend Unit with County, specifically, when restarting the application to initialize ORM.  [Note: I'm attempting single-table inheritance]

ORM is managing my DB schema: `this.ormsettings.dbcreate=dropcreate`

When I remove County.cfc from the models directory, ORM initializes and the application starts normally.  When I put County.cfc back into the models directory, the error occurs again.

ColdFusion version 10,282462 
MSSQL
IIS

Unit:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="Unit" table="Units" discriminatorColumn="type">
    <cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" column="unit_id" generator="identity">  
    <cfproperty name="name" default="" type="string" length="50"> 
    <cfproperty name="description" type="string" sqltype="varchar(max)" default="">
    <cfproperty name="active" type="boolean" default="true"> 
</cfcomponent>
```

County:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="County" table="Units" extends="Unit" discriminatorValue="county">
    <cfproperty name="officeAddress" type="string">
</cfcomponent>
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.createPrimaryKey(PersistentClass.java:322) at
org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:405) at
org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:321) at
org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:172) at
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:771) at
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addDocument(Configuration.java:586) at
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.buildConfiguration(HibernateConfiguration.java:611) at
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.initHibernateConfiguration(HibernateConfiguration.java:208) at
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.<init>(HibernateConfiguration.java:181) at
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.ConfigurationManager.initConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67) at
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateProvider.InitializeORMForApplication(HibernateProvider.java:185) at
coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateProvider.onPageRequestStart(HibernateProvider.java:151) at
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.firePageRequestStart(ApplicationFilter.java:599) at 
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:407) at
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at
coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79) at
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:204) at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414) at
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:203) at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Odd thing is that I'm already doing something similar with another entity (DiscussionPost extends Post):

Post:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="Post" table="Posts" discriminatorColumn="type">
    <cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" column="post_id" generator="identity">
    <cfproperty name="promotions" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="PostPromotion" fkcolumn="post_id" singularname="promotion">
    <cfproperty name="comments" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="PostComment" fkcolumn="post_id" singularname="comment">    
    <cfproperty name="user" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="User" fkcolumn="user_id">
    <cfproperty name="text" type="string" sqltype="varchar(1000)">
    <cfproperty name="timestamp" type="date" ormtype="timestamp">
</cfcomponent>
```

DiscussionPost:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="DiscussionPost" table="Posts" extends="Post" discriminatorValue="discussionpost">
    <cfproperty name="discussion" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Discussion" fkcolumn="discussion_id">
    <cfproperty name="title" type="string" sqltype="varchar(200)">

</cfcomponent>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Line 322 of createPrimaryKey() in PersistentClass is throwing the NPE when it tries to add columns to the primary key. Either the key does not exist, or it's getColumnIterator() is returning null.

Comment: I don't know much about discriminator use, but there's one thing about extending ORM models: properties are not inherited by default. Could it be that `id` property does not exist in the `County` model, which causes the problem that Mike described?

Comment: @Sergii, I suppose that's possible; however, in the example of Post/DiscussionPost, DiscussionPost does not declare the `id` field but it does in fact inherit it.  I confirm this by creating a new DiscussionPost, saving it, and then checking the `Posts` table in the DB: the new DiscussionPost is there!  Something is different between the two cases of Single Table Inheritence but I can't see what it is.

Comment: Just as FYI, I copied the `id` property declaration from `unit` to `county` and succeeded in getting the application to restart without error; however, when attempting to create and save a county entity after that, I was greeted with a different error telling me that the discriminator column `unittype` cannot be null.  That was just as confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. As it turns out, the answer to this was really very simple.  By doing a global search and replace on my codebase, replacing 'unit' with 'container', I was able to get the Single Table Inheritance in my application to work correctly.  Seriously.  That's all I changed and it worked. 'Unit' is obviously not a reserved word in CF because the entity `Unit` works on its own but it must have been causing problems in some internal process (perhaps in `getColumnIterator()` as @MikeCauser suggested).

Thanks to all for your suggestions.

**EDIT: This turned out to be an incidental fix, not a fix that targets the root of the problem, whatever that may be.  A real solution remains to be found.**

**EDIT 2: I'm confident now that the issue at hand had to do with ColdFusion/Hibernate internals that simply needed to be refreshed by a restart of the ColdFusion service.**

Yes, after banging my head against my desk off and on for two weeks, I restarted the ColdFusion Application Service and my problem was solved.  I've extended the container component 3 more times since then.  All appears well and I've moved on with my application.

Comment: Though doing a global search and replace DID fix the app for a short period, I am again receiving a NPE from County without any clear cause.  As a test, I created a second ORM application with the base entity `Unit` and 4 extensions: `County`, `Program`, `UserStash`, `FileGroup`.  The application works as expected, with absolutely zero NPEs.  Clearly, the name of the base component is not important.   Still working on the solution.....

Comment: Get this.  I copied my source into a new directory and setup a new datasource and then ran my application.  It worked exactly as designed with zero NPEs.  Could this have something to do with Hibernate's internal (hidden) config not correctly updating?

Comment: I'm embarrassed but very relieved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be missing the sqltype attribute for the officeAddress property in County.cfc

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be the issue you are experiencing: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HBX-54

I think the fix is to add an id property to County.cfc:

```
<cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" column="county_id" generator="identity">
```

The code above assumes that your id column is named "county_id". Does that fix your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The idea is that `County` will inherit the `id` field from `Unit`.  This is exactly what happens in the example of Post/DiscussionPost.  Also, as far as I know, a single table cannot have two primary keys.